# Linq to XML: Load an object based on attribute of a node

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

Given the following XML section from a large xml file:

```
<item id="C3DD6846593" >
    <name xml:lang="fr">Atlantique</name>
    <name xml:lang="en">Atlantic </name>
</item>
```

I'm trying to load an object in Linq based on the attribute of a node. Here is what I tried to do in the code.

```
public class MyList
    {
        public string ID {get;set;}

        public string EnName {get;set;}

        public string FrName {get;set;}

        public MyList() { }
    }
```

...... later in code

```
  AgencyList = (from x in rawSrc.Descendants("item")                          
                                select new MyList{
                                    ID = x.Attribute("id").Value
                                    EnName = x.XPathSelectElement("\\name[@lang='en']").Value,
                                    FrName =x.XPathSelectElement("\\name[@lang='fr']").Value
                                }).ToList();
```

I get " '\name[@lang='en']' has an invalid token." as the error. Is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a normal slash instead of a backslash. Additionally, you need to add the namespace of the attribute and pass in an instance of `IXmlNamespaceResolver`:

```
EnName = x.XPathSelectElement("//name[@xml:lang='en']", ns).Value,
FrName = x.XPathSelectElement("//name[@xml:lang='fr']", ns).Value
```

Comment: That was it. Was not paying attention to the fact that there was a namespace. Cheers

Comment: @Arnej65: Your original problem was not the namespace but the backslash.